# SQLite trigger before insert

Tags: database, sqlite

I am trying to create a trigger where it filters the itemID first and then checks the most highest bidNo of that itemID. bidNo has to be only +1 bigger than the last. bid is bidder.

```
CREATE TRIGGER new_bid_no
BEFORE INSERT ON BID
    BEGIN
        SELECT CASE
        WHEN (SELECT itemID
                FROM bid
                WHERE itemID = NEW.itemID
                GROUP BY itemID
        ) AND (SELECT MAX(bidNo) AS bidNo
                FROM bid
                WHERE NEW.bidNo < bidNo
                OR NEW.bidNo = (bidNo+1)
                GROUP BY itemID
        )THEN
        RAISE (ABORT, 'New bid number has to be 1 higher than the last')
    END;
END;
```

the bid table

```
CREATE TABLE BID(
buyerUsername    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
itemID            INTEGER NOT NULL,
bidNo             INTEGER NOT NULL,
bidAmount         INTEGER,
bidDate            VARCHAR(10),
bidTime            TIME,
PRIMARY KEY(buyerUsername, itemID, bidNo),
FOREIGN KEY (buyerUsername) REFERENCES BUYER(buyerUsername),
FOREIGN KEY (itemID) REFERENCES ITEM(itemID)
)
WITHOUT ROWID;
```

Comment: Post the definition of the table `bid`.

Comment: @forpas its bidder in a auction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you must define a `UNIQUE` constraint for `itemID, bidNo` and this can be done only in the `CREATE` statement of the table and not added later:

```
CREATE TABLE BID(
  buyerUsername    TEXT NOT NULL,
  itemID           INTEGER NOT NULL,
  bidNo            INTEGER NOT NULL,
  bidAmount        INTEGER,
  bidDate          TEXT,
  bidTime          TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY(buyerUsername, itemID, bidNo),
  FOREIGN KEY(buyerUsername) REFERENCES BUYER(buyerUsername),
  FOREIGN KEY(itemID) REFERENCES ITEM(itemID),
  UNIQUE(itemID, bidNo)
)
WITHOUT ROWID;
```

I also changed the data types of the columns that you defined as `VARCHAR` to `TEXT`, because there is no `VARCHAR` data type in SQLite. Even if you defined it as such it will be `TEXT`. Also there is no data type `TIME`.

Now your trigger can be written like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER new_bid_no
BEFORE INSERT ON BID 
WHEN NEW.bidNo <> COALESCE((SELECT MAX(bidNo) FROM bid WHERE itemID = NEW.ItemID AND bidNo < NEW.bidNo), 0) + 1
BEGIN
   SELECT RAISE (ABORT, 'New bid number has to be 1 higher than the last');
END
```